# Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java

while compiling java program we are getting "Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details".
Why we are getting this error?

Comment: copy the full stack trace please.

Comment: Have you tried doing what it suggests?

Answer (score 4):

Probably because you're not using generics properly. Perhaps you're mixing legacy code with generic code.

Here's a quote fro [the official trail on type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> ```
> Note: WarningDemo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> ```
>
> *This can happen when using an older API that operates on raw types, as shown in the following WarningDemo program:*
>
> ```
> public class WarningDemo {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Box<Integer> bi;
>         bi = createBox();
>     }
>
>     static Box createBox() {
>         return new Box();
>     }
> }
> ```

I suggest you follow the advice, and add the `-Xlint:unchecked` option when compiling. This should reveal the which parts of the code that are problematic.

Comment: am not using generics in my class,i am wrote simple java class using collections.

Comment: "*am not using generics in my class*" -- That may be the exact problem. Are you using any `List`, `Set` or other `Collection`? In that case, you shouldn't use their *raw types*.

Comment: import java.util.*;
class ListIteratorDemo 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
  l.add("krishna");
  l.add("bargavi");
  l.add("venkata");
  l.add("rama");
  l.add("sesha");
        l.add("adithya");
  System.out.println(l);
  ListIterator ltr = l.listIterator();
  while(ltr.hasNext())
  {
   String s = (String)ltr.next();
             if(s.equals("venkata"))
   {
    ltr.remove();
   }
   System.out.println(l);
  }
 }
}

Comment: I building using jenkins so how do i do "I suggest you follow the advice, and add the -Xlint:unchecked option when compiling. This should reveal the which parts of the code that are problematic."

Comment: how to `Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`?

Comment: @AshishKarpe Where do we place those "-Xling:whatever-is-suggested" options please when compiling in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

This option enables/disables specific warnings. It seems that your code produces these warnings. If you are using IDE as well pay attention on the warning it produces too. It may be very helpful.

And try to do what compiler offers you: just recompile with this option and see what will happen.

Comment: Where do we place those "-Xling:whatever-is-suggested" options please when compiling in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, that is because you need to declare a List object, say (e.g.), without omitting '<' and '>':

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I tried to declare object in stack without  in NetBeans, and NetBeans compiled my code with no error messages. Maybe, things are different with javac compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you compile a Java file that includes a `java.util.*;` package, it must be  recompiled with `-xlint`.

Also, Check your jdk version (using `java -version`). I am sure it must old. Install a new version of Java (like version 7) and you won't get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by the jdk version mismatch, not necessarily the old jdk version but any version other than expected can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

java reinstall or update and set up

or

sometime issues in old caches

- clear caches in your system
- restart your system

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).