# Program uses unchecked or unsafe operations, recompile using -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java

I am just trying out a simple code and getting this Note. Program is compiled and executed successfully, but this note disturbs me.

```
Program uses unchecked or unsafe operations, recompile using -Xlint:unchecked for details
```

- What are the unsafe or unchecked operations here? And what is meant by unsafe or unchecked operation?
- What does `-Xlint:Unchecked` do? And how to use it?

I used it like this while compiling:

```
 javac <filename>.java -Xlint:unchecked
```

and the result is

```
[unchecked] unchecked call to add <E> as a member of raw type HashSet h.add("raj");
```

and got it in other lines as well what does it mean?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class HashSetDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashSet h = new HashSet();
        h.add("raj");
        h.add(11);
        h.add(22.2);
        h.add('c');
        h.add(true);
        h.add(null);
        h.add(null);
        System.out.println("Duplicate:"+h.add(11));
        System.out.println(h);
        Iterator itr = h.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422162/recompile-with-xlintunchecked-for-details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a type for the `HashSet`:

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
```

But then you are only able to put `String` instances inside it.

In your example your try to add `String`, `Integer`, `Float`, and `Boolean` instances into it which makes no sense.

Take a look at [the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) to learn about Generics.